# Does it make sense to use batch normalization in deep (stacked) or sparse auto-encoders?

Tags: deep-neural-networks, autoencoders, batch-normalization

Does it make sense to use batch normalization in deep (stacked) or sparse auto-encoders?

I cannot find any resources for that. Is it safe to assume that, since it works for other DNNs, it will also make sense to use it and will offer benefits on training AEs?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see why this would not be the case. As long as you use a similar batch optimizer the same principle should apply.